# Parametrizing string in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

How to replace a method signature to accept parameterized strings without using param keywords. I have seen this functionality in Console.WriteLine(). 
e.g.

```
public void LogErrors(string message, params string[] parameters) { }
```

Scenario:

I have an error login function called

```
LogErrors(string message)
{
    //some code to log errors
}
```

I am calling this function at different locations in the program in a way that the error messages are hardcoded. e.g.:

```
LogError("Line number " + lineNumber + " has some invalid text");
```

I am going to move these error messages to a resource file since I might change the language (localization) of the program later. In that case, how can I program to accept curly bracket bases parameterized strings? e.g.:

```
LogError("Line number {0} has some invalid text", lineNumber)
```

will be written as:

```
LogError(Resources.Error1000, lineNumber)
```

where Error1000 will be "Line number {0} has some invalid text"

Comment: If I had a penny each time someone writes his own logging library, I would be rich. [NLog](http://nlog-project.org) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks Serge, that's a helpful tip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want *two* methods:

```
public void LogErrors(string message, params string[] parameters)
{
    LogErrors(string.Format(message, parameters));
}

public void LogErrors(string message)
{
    // Use methods with *no* formatting
}
```

I *wouldn't* just use a single method with the `params`, as then it'll try to apply formatting even if you don't have any parameters, which can make things harder when you want to use "{" and "}" within a simple message without any parameters.

Comment: Just wonder what is the best practice in keeping the error messages in a program. Where do you keep error messages in a program? Is it in a resource file as I have done or some other way?

Comment: @Sriwantha: It depends who the target of the error messages is. Do you need them to be localized or not? That's the big question.

Comment: of cause if the app is localized we need to use resource files. However, I am asking where do you maintain application specific strings in general? Note that they are constant values, so do you advice to shift all the string values to let's say to private const string at the beginning of the class? Need a good design advice.

Comment: @Sriwantha: It depends on how they're being used. For exception messages which aren't going to be localized, I just keep them inline.

Answer (score 12):

Just call `String.Format` in your function:

```
string output = String.Format(message, parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically use [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method:

```
public void LogError(string format, params string[] errorMessages)
{
   log.WriteError(String.Format(
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                          format, 
                          errorMessages));
}
```

Comment: Logs should use InvariantCulture